# way to transform vtt, ttml, srv3, srv2 or srv1 insto srt?

Tags: debian, youtube-dl, video-subtitles

When I use youtube-dl to list-subs I usualy get something like the following -

```
en       vtt, ttml, srv3, srv2, srv1
```

Is there a way to transform any of these subtitle formats to .srt format using tools on console or having a GUI ?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question but just for information, `.vtt` files are supported by VLC Media Player. If the subtitles file has the same name as the movie file, it will appear automatically in the subtitles menu in VLC, otherwise a simple drag and drop will do the job. I haven't tried with other file types (`ttml`, `srv3`, `srv2`, `srv1`) though

Answer (score -1):

There are plenty of such programs/services out there.
[Use your search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=vtt+to+str&ia=web).

In few seconds I found quite a few: (web services)

[VTT to SRT Converter - Tool Slick](https://toolslick.com/conversion/subtitle/vtt-to-srt) (tested and it works)

[Online tool for changing many types of subtitles to srt](https://subtitletools.com/convert-to-srt-online) (tested and it works)

(programs)

[Elgindy VTT to SRT Converter 1.2.0](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Video/Other-VIDEO-Tools/Elgindy-VTT-to-SRT-Converter.shtml) (tested, and works, standalone, for windows, you can use wine to run it; it's even [on github](https://github.com/zezo010/Elgindy-VTT-to-SRT-Subtitle-Converter))

There are [others on github](https://github.com/topics/vtt-to-srt) too. 
Closest would be:

[isaacbernat/netflix-to-srt](https://github.com/isaacbernat/netflix-to-srt) (it works and before you say it doesn't read their description, it takes directories as arguments; you can obviously change it on your own - there is a source)

Comment: I was looking for desktop or console tools rather than web services. The idea is to do the same in-house or within the system, not take it outside. This is what the whole unix.stackexchange network is for, not for web services otherwise I would have explicitly asked for.

Comment: The third one ([Elgindy VTT to SRT Converter 1.2.0](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Video/Other-VIDEO-Tools/Elgindy-VTT-to-SRT-Converter.shtml)) is desktop. Read description.

Comment: It's even on github. There are others on github as well - read edited answer.